# How does one filter unanswered questions for 1) my tags 2) in order of most recent?

Tags: support, tags, unanswered-questions, filtering, sorting

I can get the most recent, unanswered questions easily enough. Filtering for my tags, however, breaks the ordering so I'm not presented with recent questions. At the moment, the top 5 questions in that list are from more than 2 months ago.

I'd like to get a list of:

- *unanswered* questions
- that have no accepted answer
- and are sorted so the most recent are at the top

Given that I hang out mostly on the main site (instead of, say the sysadmin or the electrical engineering site), I'd REALLY like to be able to filter this further to reject any question asked by someone with less than a minimum reputation level.

Comment: Rejecting user questions offhand because of reputation level seems to me counter productive to the whole intent of the site.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to have the "unanswered questions" page show me questions that I have input on. For example, when I go to that page now, the vast majority of questions are on topics with which I have no experience. I want to see unanswered questions on only those topics where I feel like I can make a solid contribution. (I don't answer questions much anymore because it's such a pain in the ass to filter through all the idiots who are asking us to do their homework - another good reason to allow me to filter by reputation.)

Answer (score 5):

[Here's what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20isanswered%3ano%20is%3aq%20closed%3a0):

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20isanswered%3ano%20is%3aq%20closed%3a0
```

It search for:

- questions only
- not answered
- not closed
- with any of your favorite tags

There's no filtering by user reputation.