# User-friendly way to filter My Tags with additional criteria?

Tags: discussion, support

I've been bothered for a while with my inability to properly filter questions with multiple criteria. Even after reading the search topic in the *Help Center* I am still left with a couple of questions:

- What is **objectively** the easiest and fastest way to filter questions that contain *My Tags* **and** other criteria such as *Unanswered*, *Newest or any other combination of tags?

  I've read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289024/5759072) that I can use a type of search `regex` like this:

  `intags:mine isanswered:no is:q closed:0`

  Which would display open questions that contain *"My Tags"* that have not been answered yet.

  So I am aware that this option exists, but is there an easier way to do this? Am I failing to see a button or some series of options somewhere on the site where one could sort this?
- If using these parameters is really the only way, then is there a way to **save search parameters** directly on StackOverflow so they can quickly be reused later? I know that I could just save them in a sticky note or even in a text file, but I would really like to know if there is a better way.
- If the answer to some of the questions above is negative, then my next question is **"Why"**, why would there not be an easier way to manage our search patterns? I do understand it's a stack dedicated to code, so it makes sense from that perspective but that is no reason to make things difficult just for the sake of consistency. In the end writing code is about automation and simplifying difficult or otherwise impossible tasks.

Just to clarify, I am not looking for a magic button that will do absolutely everything I want including serving me breakfast with whipped cream and cherries on top. I want to know *if* there is a more user-friendly system of searching and filtering content on Stack Overflow, and if not then what is the justification for not implementing one?

Comment: They are actually implementing that. It's an early-release opt-in (6-8 waiting time) feature called [custom question lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327816/332043). Still a work in progress and misses some features, but it sounds close to what you're asking about

Comment: That sounds great, It seems that's exactly what I was looking for. Good to know that this is in the works, but for now is manually entering search parameters the fastest way to filter?

Comment: Yeah, for now, searching is the easiest way (and also the only one running with live data). You'll need to refresh to see new questions though

Comment: Small nitpick - what is easiest or fastest is almost never objective -- you have to account for users' preferences for criteria, as well as environmental variables, as well as additional per-user variables like muscle memory, intelligence, frequency of use, etc.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't just save the search to a browser bookmark?

Comment: @Makyen Not particularly, I was just interested to see if there is an integrated way to do this.